# Composer could not find a composer.json file in /app

Tags: docker-compose, composer-php

I'm referring to this [site](https://gist.github.com/andyshinn/e2c428f2cd234b718239) which I thought I can avoid building another Dockerfile. I wish I can rely everything in the docker-compose.yml to initiate composer installation on subdirectory/other dir than `app`. Any idea how can I configure this workdir param

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include `working_dir: /app` in your `docker-compose.yml` file. It acts the same as if you had `WORKDIR /app` in your Dockerfile. So, in the end, it should look like:

```
app:
restart: 'yes'
image: php:7
command: php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 /app/index.php
ports:
  - "8000:8000"
working_dir: /app
volumes:
  - .:/app
```

Comment: my composer.json file is in root dir. there is no /app. and everything is working on windows 10. but this error occurs only in window 7 where i use docker toolbox.